# swift programming syntax issue

Tags: swift

What does it mean in swift when there is a period bewteen two variables and/or functions. I know it's very simple but I can't find an answer and it's driving me crazy. An example program is below:

```
 “let string1 = "hello"
 let string2 = " there"
 var welcome = string1 + string2
 // welcome now equals "hello there”


 let exclamationMark: Character = "!"
 welcome.append(exclamationMark)
 // welcome now equals "hello there!”
```

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks. https://itun.es/ca/jEUH0.l

What's the use of the period between welcome and append? What does it do?

Comment: In the "A Swift Tour" chapter of the same book: *"Use dot syntax to access the properties and methods of the instance."*

Answer (score 1):

That's how you call function "append" for instance "welcome", passing "exclamationMark" as the parameter. In Objective-C this would be:

```
[welcome append: exclamationMark];
```

In general, the period is how you access any member (method or property) of an instance.

Answer (score 0):

It's called "dot syntax" and that's what is used to access members, functions or properties of that instance.